# CSS to apply multiple selectors for one class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

this is HTML

```
<p>x1</p> <p>x2</p>
```

and i want css to select first < p> then use " :after " selector :

```
p:nth-child(1):after{
  content:"- X1 !";
}
```

what this should basically done is add " - X1 ! " after first   < p>
but it doesnt work, how to do it ?

Comment: `p:nth-child(1)` does not mean "select the first `p`". It means "select the first child inside the parent element *if* it's a `p`". What does your full HTML look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work, see here: http://jsbin.com/ujolek/2/edit

You can also do this:

```
p:first-child:after{  content:"- X1 !" }
```

Comment: +1 for being 18 seconds faster, and for coming up with the same answer.

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this !, i just tried it again with my project and it seems to be working fine .. -conufsed- but ya thanks !